# how can i delete a file with wrong path, created by java program

Tags: java, file, java-io

How can I delete a file made up of a java program. I have a file named `con.txt` located in a directory, this file is made up of before, when I learned java language. But something is wrong (probably the path) when I try to open the file then notepad display 'can not file `\\. \ con.txt`, do you want create new file '[image]'. I try to create a new file but create a new one and the old file still exists. Can you show me how to delete this file, thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried pressing the "Delete" key on your keyboard?

Comment: From the image that you posted in your question, you are trying to open file `con.txt` via the _Quick Access_ in Windows File Explorer. Sometimes incorrect information is displayed in Windows File Explorer. If you know the actual path to the file, try to navigate to that folder and then delete the file `con.txt`

Comment: I have tried it but still the same way, but successfully deleted when using 3rd party software @luk2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the entire program folder.
You may want to try using third-party software for that.

Comment: thanks you! 
I have successfully deleted it